How to align the arc with the coords?
I want to align the arc with the coords. It should follow the angle when I change the middle point.

import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from mathutils import Vector
from math import cos, sin, radians, degrees, atan2, acos

coords = [Vector((-1, -1, 1)), Vector((1, -1, -1)), Vector((1, 1, 1))]
colors = [(0, 0, 0, 1)] * len(coords)

def draw():
    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("POLYLINE_SMOOTH_COLOR")
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, "LINE_STRIP", {"pos": coords, "color": colors})
    shader.uniform_float("lineWidth", 0.8)
    batch.draw(shader)

    # Draw arc
    line = coords[2] - coords[0]
    start_vec = (coords[0] - coords[1]).normalized()
    end_vec = (coords[2] - coords[1]).normalized()
    angle = degrees(acos(max(min(start_vec.dot(end_vec), 1.0), -1.0)))
    radius = min(bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_distance / (angle / 10), 1)

    if 0 < angle != 180:
        start_angle = degrees(atan2(end_vec.y, end_vec.x))
        end_angle = degrees(atan2(start_vec.y, start_vec.x))
        draw_arc(coords[1], radius, start_angle, end_angle)

def draw_arc(center, radius, start_angle, end_angle, color=(0, 0, 0, 1), line_width=0.8):
    coords = [(center.x + radius * cos(radians(angle % 360)), center.y + radius * sin(radians(angle % 360)), center.z)
              for angle in (range(int(start_angle), int(end_angle)) if start_angle < end_angle else range(int(start_angle), int(end_angle) + 360))]

    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("POLYLINE_SMOOTH_COLOR")
    colors = [color] * len(coords)
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, "LINE_STRIP", {"pos": coords, "color": colors})
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("lineWidth", line_width)
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')


After running the example and refreshing the viewport, nothing is displayed (it does not work, old preference import to 4.3). But the factory settings is work, I think this is a internal bugs.

The main issue is that you need to treat it as a 3d arc, not a 2d arc.
So you need to find a local coordinate system (in my code, given by localX, localY, localZ unit, orthogonal and right-hand-ruled vectors) where Z is the normal of the arc's plane.
Work the angles in the local 2d system and convert back:
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
import math
from math import cos, sin, radians, degrees, atan2, acos
import numpy as np

coords = [Vector((1, -1, -1)), Vector((0, 0, 1)), Vector((-1, 1, -1))]
colors = [(0, 0, 0, 1)] * len(coords)


def draw():
    
    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("POLYLINE_SMOOTH_COLOR")
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, "LINE_STRIP", {"pos": coords, "color": colors})
    shader.uniform_float("lineWidth", 0.8)
    batch.draw(shader)


    #draw arc
    
    #angle steps of 1 degree
    angleStep = math.pi / 180.0
    
    #gets center, radius and local coordinate system vectors
    cx, cy, cz, r, startAngle, endAngle, localX, localY, localZ = getArcLocalParams(*coords) 
    
    #gets coordinates in the local system
    arcCoords = getArcLocalCoords(cx, cy, cz, r, startAngle, endAngle, angleStep)
      
    #converts coordinates to global
    arcCoords = convertLocalToGlobal(arcCoords, localX, localY, localZ)
    
    # Draw arc
    draw_arc(arcCoords)

def draw_arc(coords, color=(0, 0, 0, 1), line_width=0.8):

    coords = list([(x,y,z) for x,y,z in coords])

    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin("POLYLINE_SMOOTH_COLOR")
    colors = [color] * len(coords)
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, "LINE_STRIP", {"pos": coords, "color": colors})
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("lineWidth", line_width)
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')


def getArcLocalParams(p1, p2, p3):
    
    #helpers
    v1 = p2 - p1 
    v2 = p3 - p1 #full cord of the arc
    
    #local axes (where Z is normal to the arc's plane)
    localX = v2.normalized() #local X is aligned with the cord
    localZ = v1.cross(v2).normalized()
    localY = localZ.cross(localX)
    
    
    # arc points in local coordinates
    l1x = localX.dot(p1)
    l1y = localY.dot(p1)
    
    l2x = localX.dot(p2)
    l2y = localY.dot(p2)
    
    l3x = localX.dot(p3)
    l3y = localY.dot(p3)
    
    # in theses local coordinates, all points have the same localZ
    # including the center Z
    cz = localZ.dot(p1)
    
    
    #center X is in the center of the cord
    cx = (l1x + l3x) / 2.0

    #this commented section is just equation solving for creating the code
    #center Y given by len(p-center)² = r² for all points   
    #(l1x - cx)**2 + (l1y - cy)**2 = r**2
    #(l2x - cx)**2 + (l2y - cy)**2 = r**2 
    #no need for a third equation since we already have centerX = cx

    #expanding the equations
    #l1x ** 2 - 2*l1x * cx  + l1y**2 - 2*l1y*cy = 
    #l2x ** 2 - 2*l2x * cx  + l2y**2 - 2*l2y*cy 
    
    #isolating cy
    #l1x**2 - l2x**2 - 2*cx*(l1x-l2x) +l1y**2 - l2y**2  = 2*cy*(l1y-l2y) 
    
    xDiff = l1x - l2x #helper
    
    cy = (0.5 * (l1x + l2x) * xDiff - cx*xDiff) / (l1y-l2y) + 0.5*(l1y+l2y)
    r = math.sqrt((l1x - cx)**2 + (l1y - cy)**2) 
    
    #angles
    startAngle, endAngle = getAngleSpan(l1x, l1y, l3x, l3y, cx, cy)
    
    return cx, cy, cz, r, startAngle, endAngle, localX, localY, localZ

def getAngleSpan(localX1, localY1, localX3, localY3, centerX, centerY):
    startAngle = math.atan2(localY1 - centerY, localX1 - centerX)
    endAngle = math.atan2(localY3 - centerY, localX3 - centerX)
    
    # we are working counterclockwise (math standard), 
    #if end < start, instead of flipping we adjust the end
    # (or we may get the wrong portion of the arc) 
    if endAngle < startAngle:
        endAngle += 2 * math.pi
        
    return startAngle, endAngle

#creates an array of local coordinates 
#very similar to your list of coordinates, but with an optimized library
#returns an array with shape (point_count, 3)
def getArcLocalCoords(cx, cy, cz, r, start_angle, end_angle, angleStep):
                
    angles = np.arange(start_angle, end_angle + angleStep, angleStep)
    sins = np.sin(angles)
    coss = np.cos(angles)
    
    xs = r * coss + cx
    ys = r * sins + cy
    zs = np.full(xs.shape, cz)
    
    coords = np.stack([xs, ys, zs], axis=1)
    
    return coords


# converts local coordinates into global coordinates 
# a coordinate conversion without scaling and translation is just 
# a 3d matrix multiplication
def convertLocalToGlobal(coords, localX, localY, localZ):
    
    converter = np.stack([localX, localY, localZ], axis=1)
    converter = converter.reshape((1,3,3))
    
    #for matrix multiplication, vectors are [3,1] matrices   
    coords = coords.reshape((-1,3,1)) 
    
    result = np.matmul(converter, coords)
    result = result.reshape((-1,3)) #remove the dimension we added before
    
    return result
    
draw()


Special thanks to the first answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076177/3d-coordinates-of-circle-center-given-three-point-on-the-circle

Geometry nodes version
Just for fun


The code could probably be much simpler if you looked at the C++ code implementation of the "Arc" node :D

@MarkusvonBroady, don't give me ideas hahaha. How do you see that?

I think the questioner wants to draw an included angle.
